# Getting an error when trying to use Promise

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm not sure whether this question is too specific. I'm using firebase inside a function that updates the database:

```
UpdatePeerNotification = (content) => {
        firebase.database().ref('users').child(this.props.match.params.username).
        .update('something)
    }
```

If I call it normally as this.updatePeerNotification('abc'); it's working
But when trying to use

```
Promise(this.updatePeerNotification('abc')).then(() => do something))
```

Or

```
this.updatePeerNotification('abc').then(() => do something))
```

it throws the following error:
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): undefined is not a promise

How can it be that calling the function regularly works but attaching the .then gets that error. Also, after refreshing the page, the function is being called without an error

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not returning a promise (or anything else) from `UpdatePeerNotification`, which leads to the caller trying to call `then` on `undefined` (the default return value for functions not returning any value).

You're probably looking to return the result of `update()`, which is a promise that resolves when the update completes on the server:

```
UpdatePeerNotification = (content) => {
    return firebase.database().ref('users').child(this.props.match.params.username).
        .update('something)
}
```

Comment: Great it really makes sense thanks a lot for your answer!

Answer (score 0):

When the return type is Promise you should handle rejection in the method

```
      updatePeerNotification('abc').then(() => dosomething).catch(function (error){return Promise.reject(error)}))
```

This should help.

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out

Answer (score 0):

Every time you use Promise, you have to either Resolve it or reject it depending on your situation. You can only do .then once you handle that. For debugging purpose, I personally use chrome console to see promise status. So, I would just recommend checking the status for Promise in your following function.

```js
UpdatePeerNotification = (content) => {
    return firebase.database().ref('users').child(this.props.match.params.username).
        .update('something)
}
```

One example of checking Promise status is here:

```js
var promise1 = new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
  resolve(23);
});

promise1.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value);
  /* expected output: 23
  Promise {<resolved>: undefined}
__proto__: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved"
[[PromiseValue]]: undefined
*/
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: No problem. @sir-haver